# Why are the compile dependencies of my library leaking through?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm working with Gradle 3.4.1.

I have a library (let's call it *utils*) built with the Gradle java-library plugin which results in a nice JAR file. This is the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
// public API
api group: "org.postgresql", name: "postgresql", version: "9.2-1004-jdbc4"    
api group: "log4j", name: "log4j", version: "1.2.17"

// implementation specific
implementation group: "commons-configuration", name: "commons-configuration" , version: "1.10"
implementation group: "commons-lang", name: "commons-lang" , version: "2.6"
}
```

Now my project includes this library as well as some other Apache Commons libraries:

```
dependencies {
compile group: "com.foo", name: "utils", version: "6.+", changing: true
compile group: "org.apache.commons", name: "commons-lang3", version: "3.5"
compile group: "commons-io", name: "commons-io" , version: "2.5"
}
```

In my classpath for the project I have now the `commons-lang` library as well as the `commons-lang3` library although I specified the appropriate dependencies as `implementation`! According to the docs https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html this should be the correct way.

Here's the dependencies listing of my project:

```
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.foo:utils:6.+ -> 6.0.0
|    +--- org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1004-jdbc4
|    +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
|    +--- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10
|    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5
\--- commons-io:commons-io:2.5
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of the external dependencies `commons-lang` and `commons-configuration`?

Comment: Note that implementation dependencies will still end up as runtime dependencies - they're required on the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to exclude transitive dependencies, covered in several questions and in gradle documentation.

```
configurations {
    compile.transitive = false
}
```

or

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group:"ch.qos.logback", module:"logback-core"
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    compile ('foo:bar:0.1') {
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    }
}
```